# Setting JSON data to HttpPost does not work

Tags: android, json, apache, http, post

i'm new in working with JSON, trying to send the JSON data with a HTTP Post request. But at all, the resulting request does not content the JSON data. Do you have an idea what i'm doing wrong?

```
        JSONObject searchASongJSSON = new JSONObject();
        searchASongJSSON.put("artist", artist);
        searchASongJSSON.put("title", title);

        publishProgress("Creating request");

        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPostReq = new HttpPost("http://"+CONNECTION_HOST+":"+CONNECTION_PORT);
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(searchASongJSSON.toString());
        System.out.println(searchASongJSSON.toString());

        httpPostReq.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPostReq.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
        InputStream is = se.getContent();
        byte inpData[] = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(inpData);
        is.close();
        System.out.println(new String(inpData));

        httpPostReq.setEntity(se);
        System.out.println(httpPostReq.getRequestLine());

        publishProgress("Sending Request");
        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpPostReq);
```

Output is:

```
I/System.out: {"artist":"TestTitle","title":"TestInterpret"}
I/System.out: {"artist":"TestTitle","title":"TestInterpret"}
I/System.out: POST http://192.168.178.24:55555 HTTP/1.1
```

Thank you

Comment: 'resulting request does not content the JSON data.'. What is 'the resulting request' in your code? Does it differ from output?

Comment: You are opening and even reading from an input stream before you even post data with .execute(). That makes no sense. Do it after execute();

Comment: 'Output is:' ?? The output of what? Which statement(s) ?

Comment: I thought the data is send within the request line, isn't it? I'm not reading from an inputstream of the connection, i do this just for debug to check what is in the string entity. The output is the system out print, the lines display the system.out calls in the code.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I see now that it is a different input stream. But for the rest you did not answer my questions. I still do not know where your three output lines come from for instance.

Comment: I have three System.out in the code, every output line is from one System.out, means first output line is after StringEntity se = new StringEntity(searchASongJSSON.toString());, second after is.close(); and third after httpPostReq.setEntity(se); The first and second output is only to show, that the entity is successfully filled with the JSON data. Should the request not include the data from the string entity? On server side i try to decrypt the JSON data, but no data is available, just '/'.

Comment: Please do not write that all in a comment. Just write the outputs as java comment directly after the statement in your code. You let us search now.